# Parsing error when trying to validate JSON file in JSLint

Tags: json, powershell, formatting

I've created a powershell script that creates a JSON file which lists all of the files in a directory along with their size and hash codes (I know there are more efficient ways to do this but its required). For some reason, in the object that holds the file information, the first line is returning the error:
Error: Parse error on line 8:

```
...     {           "fileName": ".\app.config",         "
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

It seems clear that the attribute is of type string, but for some reason, the parser can't resolve this. **What could be causing the error with the type not being determined?**
*The JSON file is below for reference:*

#### Update:

The JSON file seems to be generating correctly for the most part but for some reason, the `name` and `version` attributes are being added to the end of the file instead of the beginning. Here is the powershell function for reference:

```
function GenerateManifest([string] $manifestPath, [string] $packageName, [string] $version, [string] $hashCode, [string] $fwVersion, [string] $outputPath)
{
    "{" > $manifestPath
    
    $obj = @{
    name = $packageName
    version = $version
    frameworkVersion = $fwVersion
    files = @() 
}

    if($outputPath)
    {
        cd $outputPath
        $files = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where {($_.FullName -notlike $manifestPath) -And (-not ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]))}

        if($files)
        { 
        """files"": [ " >> $manifestPath 
            foreach($file in $files)
            {
                if($file.name -eq $manifestPath)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $fileHash = GetFileHash($file.FullName)
                $filePath = $file | resolve-path -relative

                   $fileObj = @{
                    fileName = $filePath
                    fileSize = $file.Length
                    hashCode = $fileHash
                    }
                    $obj.files += $fileObj
            }
        }
        else
        {
            "no files found" >> $manifestPath
        }
        
    }
     $json = $Obj | ConvertTo-Json
     $json >> $manifestPath
   
}
```

**JSON file**

```
    {
"files": [ 
{
    "frameworkVersion":  "4.0.73",
    "files":  [
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3863,
                      "fileName":  ".\\app.config",
                      "hashCode":  "7638235ea4b352f3843cef18be3a3dc2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  273408,
                      "fileName":  ".\\AutoMapper.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "a1eb27bb54abacecff4305e095600ff3"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  110456,
                      "fileName":  ".\\AutoMapper.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "d7b7bd30045a09d4074635b82b454ad2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  517928,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Charts.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "54df68a0597597d59ef8f6785e38cecf"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3697448,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Data.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "52a6b8d0a244adc0bcded11de3cb0f01"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  369448,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Mvvm.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "315587898dcb938b55cc3e33e0f641b8"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  811816,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Office.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "4f281ea57cdf33e4b2869dcbf513a1eb"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1780008,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.PivotGrid.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "af5490679164c50065b880b05ef6f36a"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3480872,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "1d501f60bdbbbfa3ae7cf62375d19bb7"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  6057768,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.RichEdit.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "892793249ca1548089e180dcb897cc55"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  2008872,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "581d092a560f7e988c576702c00a066c"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  7893288,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "706a5eeb1679dcf0097ba0a87058f1a4"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1428776,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "e4f2be4b411c78b8d413bc18b12c4943"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  323368,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.DocumentViewer.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "ef07c34f55fa1274b77a628a6c10f1ad"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1578792,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Gauges.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "a2a8e6ae5e8dd53f1d054a7e7d553885"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1277736,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "83a0ac14fcdefa041ceecad2df44d484"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1527592,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "9d898230c3f44f629a15409aea5563a7"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  150312,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v15.1.Extensions.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "3f8800eeb3824d33fa428d49100ff7dc"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  105768,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Layout.v15.1.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "4b0d036bb1ca24094a3aefacff06dac5"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  453416,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "256bddea67ee489b57b129149294d55c"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1021736,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.PivotGrid.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "cffdd1d6aedd64c4bd54e8f929f41312"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  923944,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Printing.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "8e4bb641617509d0a031c70fe4d34c9d"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1564456,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Ribbon.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "4af47f8b9955d16d7c6a40979b852a7f"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3148584,
                      "fileName":  ".\\DevExpress.Xpf.Themes.MetropolisDark.v15.1.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "b9788902caed807e764cd5e4f7221834"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  61952,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Analytics.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "e4e35bc4f5a5e01ff0ea5da4f0bb51ee"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  99840,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Analytics.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "7af3b25119dd613ac7036d11c14723c0"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  12288,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.BusinessLogic.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "807637828c899af266b2c0bc7eb51e40"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  32256,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.BusinessLogic.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "082695da11b1a87e667201f2d6e38d1e"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  9728,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.BusinessLogic.Tests.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "b8e64c048b1dfcabe2175992d1d703b8"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3863,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.BusinessLogic.Tests.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "7638235ea4b352f3843cef18be3a3dc2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  17920,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.BusinessLogic.Tests.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "963589b3297526a3aa257dd9972cc2cd"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  28160,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "bb8e1aa15ea65ef416dbc95f6b266d7a"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  504,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "11143b2440633f8761d500f91fde22e1"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  52736,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "b8578dee73f5ed3310f292e757ffcb07"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  10752,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.PMT.Common.TestUtils.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "465d9beb1105b43a4420cf69077792e2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1020,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.PMT.Common.TestUtils.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "31fc7691d14f201c568f83d289400cde"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  22016,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.PMT.Common.TestUtils.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "f5f52a23b19de914421d21e37b6289e2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1145856,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.UI.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "1a60a0c53396cb3755006fedd399df4c"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1026,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.UI.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "fdcea35572295b7f5d073042c0b09094"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  384512,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.UI.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "eaabaa9cba67a0328b0669d3613b11a6"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  101888,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.ViewModels.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "f1154a8b5cf5606109252fb55f84cb1c"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1014,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.ViewModels.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "51da0e4f9f4ef7ebce39a09eebb351ab"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  226816,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.ViewModels.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "ccbaabbfc4c6dd6d3870e98f5516a977"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  260096,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.Views.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "5d92c6822e8a23d7c689e9afa97fa6f6"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1020,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.Views.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "31fc7691d14f201c568f83d289400cde"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  486912,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Common.Views.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "0b944e8f5f43b6a4fb71659a31ee27f7"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  124928,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Entity.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "410b251eddecf40362a731e61f225671"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  140800,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Entity.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "800e2565f1c2d5b5ae2185b4994aa8db"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  16450048,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.MockData.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "b4f5b2f59667a07468452dd4f9ce0b56"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  763,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.MockData.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "a1cf7992c426410633d7e00a49c4ab31"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  89600,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.MockData.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "839d94600e446f86d1e9ab89d06811bc"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  140800,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Models.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "85a5bd2b06905c45dda6b74c354b1f6d"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  13824,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Models.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "a603ac8073226553b347f5837d56c100"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  2102784,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.PmToolkit.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "6a3838e12d7f7bea67a1f7b75e4fbb4c"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1020,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.PmToolkit.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "ef1a2f747c4df9853a175e181af62459"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3974656,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.PmToolkit.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "9ebe6d3265bf865b7a2b8f24ec7c100a"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  112640,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.PMT.PMToolkit.Tests.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "cdf0b89d7eb01c33b913973b7b72d522"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  3863,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.PMT.PMToolkit.Tests.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "7638235ea4b352f3843cef18be3a3dc2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  210432,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.PMT.PMToolkit.Tests.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "7c3a22df7e6c0755f1ff7009fbe1c0ce"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  169984,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Repository.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "944d9a76212fa61834f31124dccfc914"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  757,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Repository.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "aaed095788fab055449c48ea5df49259"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  288256,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Repository.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "10d00e3fffcd39983600b6c01aa4d34f"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  68608,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Services.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "f8e3d3838e07983ff7127915150cd236"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  763,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Services.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "a1cf7992c426410633d7e00a49c4ab31"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  91648,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Gims.Mas.Pmt.Services.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "cb7c6b60e3e26e983d2002e6a8b48d6a"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  376320,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Hibiscus.Dynamic.v15_1.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "b6a3262ed51c751f16e052b60f274fc2"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  116224,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.Am.Grt.Hibiscus.Themes.v15_1.pdb",
                      "hashCode":  "42287b33b0915d339f8a1481c7ef91bd"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  269312,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.QT.Gmag.Common.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "dfd5acaa9433eab7a67b38cc3b5d6f26"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  130560,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Jpmc.QT.Shared.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "37c14eb6cb21e584ce9bbcbb56f3dec3"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  6,
                      "fileName":  ".\\lob.config",
                      "hashCode":  "07ebd88009ccc51d295c73b615f01f28"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  288768,
                      "fileName":  ".\\log4net.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "179e7321f8bacc32b2bbac8cf02613ca"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1438186,
                      "fileName":  ".\\log4net.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "cae1ac02326badf167079d6ad96ecef5"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  91648,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "801ae2682bf8bd7eea229ae01ff7cf42"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  75468,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "948616893339868ee70515c43d9e0a25"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  153416,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "1488c726a98f80c3ddc6a1d00a8d0b8b"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  124216,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "8bb973283d503c9dee003476810018c1"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  521216,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Newtonsoft.Json.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "bd8dd0829bc3dd28ae16dd34ab9a2c19"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  514743,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Newtonsoft.Json.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "54380313546c98dc96bd078a656f2275"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  586240,
                      "fileName":  ".\\NSubstitute.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "8f38627ad235c93bb3f55b772688f272"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  35848,
                      "fileName":  ".\\NSubstitute.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "ee744b30d738cec4752d23b44d5504a9"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  151552,
                      "fileName":  ".\\nunit.framework.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "4454f896213433f0bf889074375b92c8"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  583343,
                      "fileName":  ".\\nunit.framework.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "b2f25c46646c7a74fe6a65b1cada2843"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  2475,
                      "fileName":  ".\\PMT.PMToolkit.Dev.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "4e64a022868c451007e6b220dedf45e7"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  2211,
                      "fileName":  ".\\PMT.PMToolkit.Research.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "372f627e48acc6faf5ab3ecdafd13fff"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  2211,
                      "fileName":  ".\\PMT.PMToolkit.Test.dll.config",
                      "hashCode":  "3317aeffee9e4dd9bae1dd120376757f"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  200440,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Collections.Immutable.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "c519584b459c4491a150ec59979107fb"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  776808,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Collections.Immutable.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "c585777b4044d929a69e50d1ba6390d6"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  191152,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Net.Http.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "3002e884c5c15a15b68eaef3c62ff254"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  115425,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Net.Http.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "2bf947b4b9995c61aa8a427644f602d0"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  104648,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Core.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "f3f361cf367660054a96a7757d530a8f"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  174535,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Core.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "fbcbf5de95fcc69db290a85a26329aea"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  24264,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "fecbd4b8b3cba96244b455ad22779b3d"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  20236,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Interfaces.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "6e0c6eea2a37cec0c868dca0b370fb18"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  704200,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Linq.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "b5f9de367187476d737ce60f2112550f"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  1015578,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Linq.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "371f39ede66864e07136c48b2bff6cf0"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  38088,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "b64acef473237ae1bd252b4752ac7b39"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  24749,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "d3b77756b4ee9e7eada0d1d07233aa3f"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  28872,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "29d23726395ae2a0d1aae4e38c71e02c"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  15191,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "baf5792f2945a2b079189f1f4d5729d9"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  39936,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll",
                      "hashCode":  "ca609bf1f4b5553e7c5103e9efaf0ca0"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  61056,
                      "fileName":  ".\\System.Windows.Interactivity.xml",
                      "hashCode":  "1087ecd40eb8e4e21a4530111658dba7"
                  },
                  {
                      "fileSize":  467,
                      "fileName":  ".\\Config\\PMT.PortfolioManagementToolkit.Config.Json",
                      "hashCode":  "e5cb5262948398a2cac4137adf8ebb63"
                  }
              ],
    "name":  "MAS-PMT",
    "version":  "2.0.12"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON has several problems.

The first issue is not very apparent based on the error from JSONLint, but it's because the value of the `fileName` key contains an unescaped backslash `\` so it's interpreting it as an unrecognized escape sequence. Those need to be changed to `\\`.

Once you fix that, you'll realize that there's no comma `,` separating the `fileSize` and the `hashCode` keys, and that the hash codes themselves need to be quoted too since they are strings.

If you're generating this JSON with string concatenation, you should stop that and create an object within PowerShell, and then send it to `ConvertTo-Json`. Something like this perhaps (untested):

```
$obj = @{
    name = "Project name"
    version = "2.0.8"
    frameworkVersion = "4.0.73"
    files = @() 
}

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\my\Path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $fileObj = @{
        fileName = $_.Name
        fileSize = $_.Size
        hashCode = Get-MyHashCode $_
    }
    $obj.files += $fileObj
}

$json = $myObj | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried adding `[regex]::escape()` around the `fileName` in order to reformat the strings but that didn't seem to resolve the issue. How can I programmatically change the backslashes to double backslashes?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 you really need to [edit] your question to include the code you're using. Have you considered using the method I outlined? All relevant escaping would be done for you that way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm implementing you solution now, it would be too inefficient to try to do string concatenation. For some reason though, when I define `$obj`, I get the precompilation error: `unexpected token 'files' in expression or statement.` Should I add dollar signs before the attribute names?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 you shouldn't add dollar signs before those names.. I left a comma in the code by accident, see the edit now.

Comment: Just updated the post, the JSON file seems to be generating correctly for the most part but for some reason, the name and version attributes are being added to the end of the file instead of the beginning.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 it's putting them in alphabetical order. Does it really matter where they are? If so, use `$obj = [ordered]@{ ... }`.

Comment: It was just that I was getting an error when I ran it in JSLint. But its working now!